# How to use a regex variable in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following pattern to clean a piece of text (replacing the matches with null):

```
{\s{\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*(?<!\bbecause\b)(?<!\bsince\b)\"\s}\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*\"\s}
```

I have a list of relators like "because" and "since" that could change every time. So I created a separate string which is a regex itself like:

```
lookahead_string = (?<!\bbecause\b)(?<!\bsince\b)
```

And put it in my original regex pattern and changed it like the following:

```
{\s{\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*'+lookahead_string+r'\"\s}\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*\"\s}
```

But the new pattern does not match the parts of the input text that could be matched using the original regex pattern. The code I am using is:

```
    lookahead_string = ''
    relators = ["because", "since"]
    for rel in relators:
        lookahead_string += '(?<!\b'+rel+'\b)'
    text = re.sub(r'{\s{\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*'+lookahead_string+r'\"\s}\s\"[A-Za-z0-9.,\-:]*\"\s}', "", text)
    text = ' '.join(text.split())
```

What should I do to make it work?! I have already tried using `re.escape` and `format` string but none of them works in my case.

> **Edit**: I removed the input output text because I thought it is a little confusing. However, I thank @DYZ for the good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: Instead of messing up with the complex string syntax, convert the string to a Python list.

```
import ast
l = ast.literal_eval("[" + s.replace("}", "],").replace("{", "[") + "]")
#[[[[['I'], 'PRP'], 'NP'], [[[[['did'], 'VBD'], [['not'], 'RB'], 'VP'],
#  ..., 'S'], '']
```

Now you can apply simple list functions to your data and, when done, transform the list to a bracketed string.

Comment: Good suggestion, however, at some point I need to use the information regarding the depth of each element in my parse tree. So I am not quite sure if by turning the tree into a list as you mentioned I can keep the structural information of the tree.

Comment: The list is fully equivalent to the original string. However, the original string has nested brackets which, in general, cannot be parsed with regular expressions.